# Program a Pneumaticcraft Drone to target Monster Spawners?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am playing a mod pack called Crash Landing which has the Pneumaticcraft mod installed. I want to program a drone to destroy all monster spawners in a city. I have set up two GPS devices, but I can't get the drone to target the monster spawners.

I can get it to attack all mobs or destroy any (craftable) block, but I cannot get it to target mob spawners.

Can someone explain (screenshots welcome) how to program a drone in such a way that it will destroy all monster spawners?